# Prometheus - separate alarm and recovery criteria?

Tags: httprequest, prometheus, monitoring, promql

I'm using prometheus to detect pauses in inbound traffic for an API endpoint.  The query for this seems to be working nicely: alert if there's no change in HTTP requests for a given endpoint over a one-hour time period:

```
sum by(path, custom_identifier, kubernetes_namespace) (
    delta(http_request_duration_seconds_count{
        status_code="201",
        method="POST",
        path="/api/v1/path/to/endpoint"}[1h])
) == 0
```

What I *want*, though, is for this alert to resolve *immediately* upon resumption of traffic.  As currently written, it won't resolve until traffic has been restored for the same time period - `1h`.

Is this a thing that Prometheus can do?  Is there a different method of accomplishing this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
- alert: AlertName
  expr: sum by(path, custom_identifier, kubernetes_namespace) (
        delta(http_request_duration_seconds_count{
        status_code="201",
        method="POST",
        path="/api/v1/path/to/endpoint"}[1m])) == 0 #recovers after 1min if resolved
  for: 1h
```